Longtblr Environment of Tabularray Package Misfunctions with Xepersian Language Package When Cells Are Given Color
Preparing a document containing some Persian content, I've recently faced a problem with longtblr environment of Tabularray package run over Xepersian Language package.
The problem, however, seems to not exist when using tblr environment of Tabularray. Nor does it occur in longtable environment of Longtable package. Nevertheless, due to technical reasons, I insist on using longtblr of Tabularray package.
With regard to the problem, when some color is designated to a cell of a longtblr, the text inside the cell disappears. This problem cease to exist when Xepersian package is deactivated. Hence, I believe there must be some kind of a glitch either in Xepersian or Tabularray packages, causing this misfunction.
The exact preamble of the document has been provided in the MWE bellow, in addition to two example tables for the sake of comparison. The first table is a normal tblr of Tabularray, in which everything is just fine. The second table, however, is a longtblr of Tabularray, in the first row of which, no color has been designated to the cells, and again, everything is just fine. But there in the second row (of the second table), you can observe that the text has disappeared with the cells being given some color.
So, anyone has any idea on a workaround about this issue? some kind of a solution on the text disappearance in colored cells of a longtblr table with Xepersian Language package run simultaneously?
Any kind of help is much appreciated in advance.
When running this document, please note that:

Xepersian works better with Tex Live. It may not work with MikTex.

Tex Builder must be set on XeLatex.

XB Kayhan font can be downloaded from: https://cdna.p30download.ir/p30dl-graphic/4.XB.Kayhan.ttf-png_p30download.com.zip, and naturally, installed in Windows fonts folder afterwards. (Zip Password: www.p30download.com)

In case of font errors when running the code (after installation in Windows Fonts folder), XB Kayhan font must be copied in Tex Live's font folder in its installation directory as well.

Measures such as: changing the place of \usepackage{xepersian} command in the preamble, changing the language package to \usepackage{persiantex} @ LuaTex, and changing the font to \usepackage{XB Zar} were of no effect.


MWE:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    %total={195mm,297mm},
    left=10mm,
    right=10mm,
    top=18mm,
    bottom=50mm,
}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{array}
%\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{14.4mm}}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.4mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength\headheight{3.7cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{2pt}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{pics/}}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lgr}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{dgr}{gray}{0.4}
\definecolor{vdgr}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,0.3}
\definecolor{dbl}{rgb}{0,0.125,0.300}
\definecolor{blgr}{rgb}{0.5,0.58,0.65}
\definecolor{dblgr}{rgb}{0.129,0.305,0.411}
\definecolor{drd}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} 
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{chronology}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{xepersian}
%\usepackage{xecolor}
%\usepackage{persiantex} %Luatex
%\settextfont{XB Zar}
\settextfont{XB Kayhan}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xpatch}

    
    
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \SetTblrInner{rowsep=4pt}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={|X[c,m]|X[c,m]|X[c,m]|X[c,m]|},hlines={0.5mm,white,black},vlines={0.5mm,black,solid}}
        %hlines{1,3}={white}
        \SetCell[c=3]{c,m,135mm,gray9} AB &  &  & \SetCell{c,m,gray7}\textbf{CD} \\
        \SetCell{c,m,gray9} EF‌ & \SetCell{c,m,gray7} \textbf{GH} & \SetCell{c,m,gray9} HI & \SetCell{c,m,gray7} \textbf{JK} \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \SetTblrInner{rowsep=4pt}
    \begin{longtblr}{colspec={|X[c,m]|X[c,m]|X[c,m]|X[c,m]|},hlines={0.5mm,black,solid},vlines={0.5mm,black,solid}}
        %hlines{1,3}={white}
        \SetCell[c=3]{c,m,135mm} AB &  &  & \SetCell{c,m}\textbf{CD} \\
        \SetCell{c,m,gray7} EF‌ & \SetCell{c,m,gray7} \textbf{GH} & \SetCell{c,m,gray7} HI & \SetCell{c,m,gray7} \textbf{JK} \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}



unrelated but you shouldn't use inputenc, fontenc, mathptmx with xelatex. fixltx2e is no longer needed, subfigure is deprecated, remove anyfontsize, use only tcolorbox and not mdframed. Regarding your problem: you can try to set to \LTR before the table and switch back in the various cells.

Liebe @UlrikeFischer ,
thank You very much for Your valuable tips and guidance. That was the solution to the problem.
Beste Grüße
